How to remove the search engine popup when starting Google Chrome with Selenium?
Chrome starts with a popup suggesting to me that I should use a search engine from a random list. This popup inhibits Selenium functionality on certain websites that I am trying to use. Is there any argument I can pass into a ChromeOptions instance to remove this popup?
Image of Chrome with the Popup
    opt = Options()
    opt.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
    opt.add_argument("start-maximized")
    opt.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    opt.add_argument(f'--search-engine=Google') # ????
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service, options = opt)

I tried my luck with random arguments i.e. "--search-engine=Google" but no results.

Same question here with a workaround for Selenium options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78787332/selecting-default-search-engine-is-needed-for-chrome-version-127

Use below argument to hide the search engine pop
opt.add_argument("--search-engine-choice-country")
